# Does setting an ADO Command's ActiveConnection = Nothing close the underlying SQL Connection?

Tags: asp-classic, ado, adodb

I have a customer who's Classic ASP application is generating ASP_0147 errors. The first thing I'm checking is that they're closing and releasing SQL/ADO resources timeously.

Their code has the following pattern:

```
Function GetXXXXRecordSet()
  Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  With objConn 
    .CursorLocation = 3 ''adUseServer (default)
    .ConnectionString = strConnectionString
    .Open
  End With

  Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn

  '' Build command object to call SQL stored proc, snipped for brevity

  Set objRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
  objRs.Open objCmd, ,3,4 '' Cursor=adOpenStatic, Locktype=adLockBatchOptimistic

  '' Return Recordset
  Set GetXXXXRecordSet = objRs

  If Not objCmd Is Nothing Then
    objCmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing  '' Should this use a Set statement?
    Set objCmd = Nothing
  End If
  If Not ObjRs Is Nothing The Set objRs = Nothing
End Function
```

Does setting an ADO Command's ActiveConnection = Nothing close the underlying SQL Connection or does that have to be closed explicitly?

Also should the line:

```
objCmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

be:

```
Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

Oddly the first version doesn't generate an error which is why I ask.

It's been so long since I looked at ADO and my knowledge is somewhat rusty.

Comment: Should be: Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing  indeed

Comment: @Kev:  I'm curious did adding a connection .Close to the code above fix the problem?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - I've passed the recommendations back to the customer, now just got to wait and see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding was always that setting `ActiveConnection` to `Nothing` did not close the connection it just removed it from that object, this is useful for things like Recordsets where you want a fixed read-only snapshot of the Recordset (combined with settings the correct cursor options) and so don't need to keep the connection live for that Recordset (but may need the connection still open for other operations)

AFAIK only actually calling `objConn.Close` closes the connection and `Set objConn = Nothing` frees up the memory

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Re-read the MSDN docs and the phraseology they use is: "...disassociates the Command object from the current Connection".

Answer (score 2):

Closing a ADODB RS + CONN:

```
objRS.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn = Nothing
```

So should be: Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing indeed

GL!

source:

http://www.aspwebpro.com/tutorials/asp/dbconnectionclose.asp

Answer (score 2):

Been awhile for all this but wouldn't setting it to nothing just clear the object. I bet if you monitored SQL Server the connection isn't terminated then.

Comment: That's what I thought too, just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript is garbage-collected, and even provides very clear and explicit guarantees regarding the GC's timing. Setting a local variable to nothing right before it goes out of scope is completely redundant because the end of the function will do the same thing, and the GC will clean up the object.

The only question is whether the ADODB.Connection's destructor frees the database resources. I'm 99% certain that it does. If so, just letting the Connection object go out of scope will free up all associated resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct that the setting of an object to nothing releases memory by using 'Set'...

```
Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But does the underlying SQL connection get cleaned up too?

Comment: @Kev: Yes it does get cleaned up too...since you're freeing up the memory occupied by the 'objCmd.ActiveConnection', it would also be prudent to 'Set objCmd = Nothing' also!

Comment: No it doesn't, setting ActiveConnection to nothing only clears the objects reference to the Connection object, it doesn't clear the actual object